# XOR gate from default-on/default-off relays, this simplest possible?

Tags: logic

Playing nandgate to learn logical gates. Is the design below the simplest xor gate that can be built using the relays available? Seems like crossover relays allow a much simpler xor gate but don't have those there.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

"Simplest" is not well-defined so I assume you are interested in knowing if you can use less than 7 relays of types "default-off" or "default-on".

It seems that a default-off relay is essentially an "and" gate (both the "in" and the "on" input must be high for the output to be "high"). I will denote this with $\wedge$.

A default-on relay is essentially an "and" gate where one of its inputs is negated. I will denote $\neg a \wedge b$ with $a \otimes b$ (notice that $\otimes$ is not commutative!).
As a consequence, $a \otimes 1 = \neg a \wedge 1 = \neg a$ and
$$
a \vee b = \neg (\neg a \wedge \neg b) = ((a \otimes 1) \wedge (b \otimes 1)) \otimes 1.
$$
This shows that $a \vee b$ can be computed using $4$ relays.

Consider then:

$$
\begin{align*}
a \oplus b &= (\neg a \wedge b) \vee (\neg b \wedge a) = (a \otimes b) \vee (b \otimes a) \\ &=
(((a \otimes b) \otimes 1) \wedge ((b \otimes a) \otimes 1)) \otimes 1
\end{align*}
$$

This shows that $a \oplus b$ can be computed using at most $6$ relays, while your solution uses 7.

---

Following you comment it seems that you are interested in minimizing the number of relays. The following solution uses only 5 relays. Let
$
\overline{b} = \neg b = b \otimes 1$. Then:
$$
a \oplus b = (a \otimes \overline{b}) \otimes ((\overline{b} \otimes a) \otimes 1).
$$

Notice that $\overline{b}$ can be found using only one relay but it is then used twice in the expression for $a \oplus b$.
Here is the corresponding truth table:

| $a$ | $b$ | $\overline{b}$ | $a \otimes \overline{b}$ | $\overline{b} \otimes a$ | $(\overline{b} \otimes a) \otimes 1$ | $(a \otimes \overline{b}) \otimes ((\overline{b} \otimes a) \otimes 1)$ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |

An exhaustive search shows that there are no solutions using at most 4 relays. Moreover, this shows that $5$ relays suffice even when just default-off relays are available.

Comment: Thank you very much for your really good answer, helps a lot. Yes was asking mostly about less components. I'm able to do the ∨=¬(¬∧¬), https://i.imgur.com/Wn1cO0D.png, but, ⊕=(¬∧)∨(¬∧) with the OR operator, what does it look like using just the relays? Is it ¬((¬(¬∧))∧(¬(¬∧))), or can it be simplified?

Comment: I gave an expressions that computes $a \oplus b$ using just relays (i.e., $\wedge$ and $\otimes$) at the end of the (first part) of my answer. That expression requires $6$ relays. Moreover, I have added an alternative construction that uses $5$ relays. This is optimal since an exhaustive search shows that it is impossible to compute $a \oplus b$ using $4$ or less relays.